# PowerPoint - VB Macro add OnClick animation to shape

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm generating buttons using VB macro. I generated plenty of buttons, where each have action - go to slide xy. I want to somehow mark these buttons after they are clicked - for example the animation that changes color to grayscale or just simply changing their background color or removing them - I just need to mark these buttons as clicked. I have no idea how this could be done. I'm setting their target this way:

```
With oshp.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick)
  .Action = ppActionHyperlink
  .Hyperlink.SubAddress = CStr(sldID) & "," & CStr(sldInd) & "," & sldTitle
```

How can I either add animation to `oshp` (action button) on click, or execute some additional code on click (such as button remove or background color change)?